# Is there a better way to pattern match and deconstruct my tuple, while discarding the rest?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm just a couple of weeks into Scala and am finding it both enjoyable and daunting.  I'm trying to deconstruct two-tuples out of space deliminated 4 column text file.  I want to match (but not keep) the first column and drop the last one, whilst keeping the middle two (article, requests).

```
  val filteredPairs = bufferedSource.getLines().toList map { line =>
    line.trim.split("\\s+").toList

    match {
      case List("en", article, requests, _) => (article, requests)
      case _ => None
    }
  } filter { m => m != None }
```

I have also tried returning "case _ => ", without any input after hashrocket and receive Unit ().  I was fiddling with map and flatmap, but was having issues with type matching.  Maybe I need an Option somewhere, but I have a deadline and both of these solutions work for me so I'm moving on for now, but I'd like to find a more elegant solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collect` which is like `filter` + `map`. As I always say, the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) is your friend.
*(btw, you may move the `toList` conversion to the end, to take advantage of the **Iterator** returned by `getLines`)*

```
val filteredPairs =
  bufferedSource
    .getLines()
    .map(line => line.trim.split("\\s+").toList)
    .collect {
      // If it has more than four columns, this won't match.
      case "en" :: article :: requests :: _ :: Nil => (article, requests)
    }.toList
```

Comment: Hi Luis, this worked much better.  I had some issues after this post with my tuples turning into Product with serializable (which I am also learning about now).  This fixed the type issues and gave me a nice output.  Thank you.